# How to Change field type from picklist to Text field

Tags: dependent-picklist

I have two picklist fields.

**picklist1:**

- factory
- warehouse
- RS
- Retail

**picklist2:**

- factory Address
- warehouse Address

If RS/retails is selected in picklist1 then no dropdown in picklist2 it should be free text field.

Comment: You can make your picklist not restricting values. But you will need to implement this logic in a custom visualforce page.

Comment: i am new to SFDC Could anyone please share your Coding to achieve this.

Comment: I would not approach this using unrestricted picklist values. Custom Visualforce page with some JavaScript to show/hide picklist2 depending on picklist1 choice. New custom field "Other" to store your text after RS/Retail chosen. Control "Other" visibility with JavaScript too.

Answer (score 1):

If I will implement it, I will create dependent picklists. The values factory Address and warehouse address will be dependent of factory and warehouse. The second picklist must no be mandatory. No value will be dependent of RS or Retail. Also, I will create a text field that I will validate when the RS or Retail will be selected. If I need the factory and warehouse in the same text field, I could create a workflow or a Process flow to populate the same text field.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep it simple, you could create a third field of type text (**text3**), then either:

- Use [dynamic forms](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_overview.htm&type=5) to conditionally hide and display the second (**picklist2**) and third (**text3**) fields, depending on the value selected in the first field (**picklist1**). Note that currently, this will only work if these fields are on custom objects, because dynamic forms are not yet available on standard ones.
- Create a validation rule to ensure that the appropriate field (**picklist2** or **text3**) is populated depending on the value selected in the first field (**picklist1**).

Neither of these approaches require code.